# How can I extract my HTML code when this message appears?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Good evening,

Sorry to disturb you on this Friday evening with a potentially simple problem.
I'm a student in data analysis. My professor has given us a dataset dealing with video game sales comprising 16700 obs and 13 variables.
His final request was that we extract our code in HTML.
However, when I want to extract it, I get this error message:

[image]

However, when I skim the supposedly "untraceable" dataset, it actually runs :

[image]

Immediately afterwards, I installed the dataset again, but the same message keeps appearing.
Do you have a solution?

Thanks

Best regards,

I've tried reinstalling it, opening and closing the software, but nothing works.

Comment: Hi Clement Planchard, welcome to SO. [For these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121), please do not post code or error messages as images. Update your question and copy the relevant text into codeblocks instead. Thanks